# Where can I get the development packages for rsync?

Tags: application-development, gcc, make, rsync

I would like to check the code for RSync but I don't see the development files, maybe I only need GCC and Make ?

Comment: You can find the code in the online repository https://git.samba.org/?p=rsync.git;a=tree

Comment: The source code is also available here: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/rsync/rsync_3.1.1.orig.tar.gz

Comment: I'm trying to use Anjuta but after configuration it crashes when I try to check the project. :/

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question referencing Anjuta and include any log files.

Comment: I submitted a bug instead or is bug fixing part of AskUbuntu topics ? @chili555

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/anjuta/+bug/1597333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the most 'Ubuntu' way of seeing the source code for rsync, *as well as* seeing the Debian packaging and patching material, is to activate the sources by following (under Xenial):

```
Dash > Software & Updates > Ubuntu Software > Source Code
```

Ticking the 'Source Code' box and allowing the repositories to reload. Then run the following single command:

```
mkdir -v ~/Desktop/rsync_source && cd ~/Desktop/rsync_source && \
apt-get source rsync
```

If you then wish to manipulate this source i.e. alter the sources, change the build options or simply rebuild you will also need the following:

1. Some build tools:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot devscripts
   ```
2. The build dependencies for rsync:

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep rsync
   ```

**References:**

- [Ubuntu Community Docs: Updating a Deb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpdatingADeb)

Comment: I made this script to help me do it faster next time : http://paste.ubuntu.com/18097867/

Comment: Good to see you extending my answer :)

Comment: Took out the sudo part : http://paste.ubuntu.com/18100001/